# Ionic ImagePicker plugin installation problem

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I try to implement Ionic ImagePicker functions but then I run it on my mobile phone
I get this error :

```
[app-scripts] [19:21:32]  console.warn: Install the ImagePicker plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker'
```

even that I already Installed it  a lot of times and tried few version.
I also can see the plugin directory installed on my project and I have no idea whats wrong.
I followed after few answers over the NET to solve this issue but still get the same error.

I use :

```
ionic@4.3.1
```

`cordova@6.5.0`   ( It was the latest version but I tried to downgrade becau some answers said that solved their problem).

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.3
```

I very appreciate any help

Comment: Hey buddy! did you find the solution? i didnt, having the same problem :(

Comment: Also trying to resolve this issue now, have you found a solution yet? :)